How to update the screen after a button click?
I have some code that creates rows of data items in a LazyColumn. Those rows have headers associated with the data. I want to be able to click on one of two headers in the form of buttons and have the data in that LazyColumn sorted differently. I can see everything just fine but when I click on one of the two buttons, nothing changes. What am I doing wrong, please?
Here is the log output:
Debug: Retrieving all patients
Debug: Retrieved 10 Patient objects
Debug: About to loop through 10 patients 
Debug: Calling VisitList with orderedList of size: 10
Debug: VisitList processing orderedList of size 10
Debug: About to loop through 10 patients 
Debug: Calling VisitList with orderedList of size: 10
Debug: VisitList processing orderedList of size 10
Debug: Sorting based on date
Debug: Sorting based on name

As you can see from that, clicking on the sorting buttons doesn't result in call to VisitList
My code looks like this.
class InsertionVisitHistoryScreen: Screen {
@Composable
override fun Content() {
    val navigator = LocalNavigator.currentOrThrow
    val patientRealm = openPatientRealm()
    val patients: RealmResults<Patient> = retrieveAllPatients(patientRealm)

    val visitList = remember { mutableStateListOf<VisitRowData>() } // creates a MutableList
    var orderedList by remember { mutableStateOf(visitList.toList()) }
    var firstTimeThrough = true

    MaterialTheme {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Text("Insertion Visit History")

            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(bottom = 20.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
            ) {
                Button(onClick = {
                    closeGenericRealm(patientRealm)
                    navigator.pop()
                }) {
                    Text("Back")
                }
            }

            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(bottom = 20.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
            ) {
                Button(onClick = {
                    Logger.d("Sorting based on name")
                    visitList.sortedWith(compareBy { it.getName() })
                    orderedList = visitList.toList()
                }, modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp).padding(end = 180.dp)
                ) {
                    Text("Name")
                }

                Button(onClick = {
                    Logger.d("Sorting based on date")
                    visitList.sortedWith(compareBy { it.visitDate })
                    orderedList = visitList.toList()
                }, modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
                ) {
                    Text("Visit Date")
                }
                Text("         Pellet Amount", textAlign = TextAlign.Center, modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 15.dp).wrapContentHeight(align = Alignment.CenterVertically))
                Text("           Lot number(s)" , textAlign = TextAlign.Center, modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 15.dp).wrapContentHeight(align = Alignment.CenterVertically))
            }

            Logger.d("About to loop through " + patients.size + " patients ")

            if(firstTimeThrough) {
                firstTimeThrough = false
                val visitRowDataArray = mutableListOf(VisitRowData())

                for (patient in patients) {
                    for (visit in patient.visits) {
                        val visitRowData = VisitRowData()
                        visitRowData.patientFirstName = patient.firstName
                        visitRowData.patientLastName = patient.lastName
                        visitRowData.patientLast4OfSSN = patient.lastFourOfSSN
                        visitRowData.visitDate = convertLongDateToString(visit.visitDate)

                        //Create an array of pellets
                        var pelletArray: Array<Pellet> = arrayOf(Pellet())
                        var lotArray: Array<String> = arrayOf("")

                        for (pellet in visit.pelletsUsed) {
                            pelletArray += pellet
                            lotArray += pellet.lotNumber
                        }

                        visitRowData.pelletsUsed = pelletArray
                        visitRowData.lotNumbers = lotArray

                        visitRowDataArray += visitRowData
                    }
                }

                visitRowDataArray.removeIf { it.getTotalPelletAmount() == 0}

                visitList.clear()

                visitList.addAll(visitRowDataArray)

                orderedList = visitList.toList()
            }

            Logger.d("Calling VisitList with orderedList of size: " + orderedList.size)
            VisitList(orderedList)
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun VisitList(orderedList: List<VisitRowData>) {
    Logger.d("VisitList processing orderedList of size " + orderedList.size)

    LazyColumn {
        orderedList.forEachIndexed{index, visitItem ->
            item{
                Card(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .wrapContentHeight()
                    .padding(5.dp),
                    elevation = 10.dp) {
                        CreateARow(visitItem)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun DropdownList(itemArray: Array<String>, selectedIndex: Int, modifier: Modifier, onItemClick: (Int) -> Unit) {

    var showDropdown by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(true) }
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {

        // button
        Box(
            modifier = modifier //                    .background(Color.Gray)
                .clickable { showDropdown = true },
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Text(text = itemArray[selectedIndex], modifier = Modifier.padding(3.dp))
        }

        // dropdown list
        Box {
            if (showDropdown) {
                Popup(
                    alignment = Alignment.TopCenter,
                    properties = PopupProperties(
                        // CAN'T FIND THIS PARAM -> excludeFromSystemGesture = true,
                    ),
                    // to dismiss on click outside
                    onDismissRequest = { showDropdown = false }
                ) {

                    Column(
                        modifier = modifier
                            .heightIn(max = 90.dp)
                            .verticalScroll(state = scrollState)
                            .border(width = 1.dp, color = Color.Gray),
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                    ) {

                        itemArray.onEachIndexed { index, item ->
                            if (index != 0) {
                                Divider(thickness = 1.dp, color = Color.LightGray)
                            }
                            Box(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .background(Color.Gray)
                                    .fillMaxWidth()
                                    .clickable {
                                        onItemClick(index)
                                        showDropdown = !showDropdown
                                    },
                                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                            ) {
                                Text(text = item)
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun CreateARow(visit: VisitRowData) {
    var selectedIndex by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val buttonModifier = Modifier.width(120.dp)

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(bottom = 3.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically

    ) {
        Text(
            text = visit.getName(),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(3.dp) //                                .background(Color.LightGray)
            ,
        )

        Text(
            text = visit.visitDate,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(3.dp) //                                .background(Color.LightGray)
            ,
        )

        Text(
            text = visit.getTotalPelletAmount().toString(),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(3.dp) //                                .background(Color.LightGray)
            ,
        )

        DropdownList(
            itemArray = visit.getPelletToLotNumberArray(),
            selectedIndex = selectedIndex,
            modifier = buttonModifier,
            onItemClick = { selectedIndex = it })
    }
}

}

OK, had to introduce a variable to inspect that gets updated in the ButtonClick event. The final working code looks like this:
class InsertionVisitHistoryScreen: Screen {
@Composable
override fun Content() {
    val navigator = LocalNavigator.currentOrThrow
    val patientRealm = openPatientRealm()
    val patients: RealmResults<Patient> = retrieveAllPatients(patientRealm)

    var visitList = remember { mutableStateListOf<VisitRowData>() } // creates a MutableList
    var orderedList by remember { mutableStateOf(visitList.toList()) }
    var firstTimeThrough = true
    var updateVisitListRows = remember {mutableStateOf(false) }

    MaterialTheme {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Text("Insertion Visit History")

            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(bottom = 20.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
            ) {
                Button(onClick = {
                    closeGenericRealm(patientRealm)
                    navigator.pop()
                }) {
                    Text("Back")
                }
            }

            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(bottom = 20.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
            ) {
                Button(onClick = {
                    Logger.d("Sorting based on name")
                    orderedList = visitList.sortedWith(compareBy { it.getName() })
                    updateVisitListRows.value = true
                }, modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp).padding(end = 180.dp)
                ) {
                    Text("Name")
                }

                Button(onClick = {
                    Logger.d("Sorting based on date")
                   orderedList = visitList.sortedWith(compareBy { it.visitDate })
                    updateVisitListRows.value = true
                }, modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
                ) {
                    Text("Visit Date")
                }
                Text("         Pellet Amount", textAlign = TextAlign.Center, modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 15.dp).wrapContentHeight(align = Alignment.CenterVertically))
                Text("           Lot number(s)" , textAlign = TextAlign.Center, modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 15.dp).wrapContentHeight(align = Alignment.CenterVertically))


                if(updateVisitListRows.value) {
                    updateVisitListRows.value = false
                    VisitList(orderedList)
                }
            }


            Logger.d("About to loop through " + patients.size + " patients ")

            if(firstTimeThrough) {
                firstTimeThrough = false
                val visitRowDataArray = mutableListOf(VisitRowData())

                for (patient in patients) {
                    for (visit in patient.visits) {
                        val visitRowData = VisitRowData()
                        visitRowData.patientFirstName = patient.firstName
                        visitRowData.patientLastName = patient.lastName
                        visitRowData.patientLast4OfSSN = patient.lastFourOfSSN
                        visitRowData.visitDate = convertLongDateToString(visit.visitDate)

                        //Create an array of pellets
                        var pelletArray: Array<Pellet> = arrayOf(Pellet())
                        var lotArray: Array<String> = arrayOf("")

                        for (pellet in visit.pelletsUsed) {
                            pelletArray += pellet
                            lotArray += pellet.lotNumber
                        }

                        visitRowData.pelletsUsed = pelletArray
                        visitRowData.lotNumbers = lotArray

                        visitRowDataArray += visitRowData
                    }
                }

                visitRowDataArray.removeIf { it.getTotalPelletAmount() == 0}

                visitList.clear()

                visitList.addAll(visitRowDataArray)

                orderedList = visitList.toList()
            }

            Logger.d("Calling VisitList with orderedList of size: " + orderedList.size)
            VisitList(orderedList)
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun VisitList(orderedList: List<VisitRowData>) {
    Logger.d("VisitList processing orderedList of size " + orderedList.size)

    LazyColumn {
        orderedList.forEachIndexed{index, visitItem ->
            item{
                Card(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .wrapContentHeight()
                    .padding(5.dp),
                    elevation = 10.dp) {
                        CreateARow(visitItem)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun DropdownList(itemArray: Array<String>, selectedIndex: Int, modifier: Modifier, onItemClick: (Int) -> Unit) {

    var showDropdown by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(true) }
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {

        // button
        Box(
            modifier = modifier //                    .background(Color.Gray)
                .clickable { showDropdown = true },
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Text(text = itemArray[selectedIndex], modifier = Modifier.padding(3.dp))
        }

        // dropdown list
        Box {
            if (showDropdown) {
                Popup(
                    alignment = Alignment.TopCenter,
                    properties = PopupProperties(
                        // CAN'T FIND THIS PARAM -> excludeFromSystemGesture = true,
                    ),
                    // to dismiss on click outside
                    onDismissRequest = { showDropdown = false }
                ) {

                    Column(
                        modifier = modifier
                            .heightIn(max = 90.dp)
                            .verticalScroll(state = scrollState)
                            .border(width = 1.dp, color = Color.Gray),
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                    ) {

                        itemArray.onEachIndexed { index, item ->
                            if (index != 0) {
                                Divider(thickness = 1.dp, color = Color.LightGray)
                            }
                            Box(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .background(Color.Gray)
                                    .fillMaxWidth()
                                    .clickable {
                                        onItemClick(index)
                                        showDropdown = !showDropdown
                                    },
                                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                            ) {
                                Text(text = item)
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun CreateARow(visit: VisitRowData) {
    var selectedIndex by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val buttonModifier = Modifier.width(120.dp)

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(bottom = 3.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically

    ) {
        Text(
            text = visit.getName(),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(3.dp) //                                .background(Color.LightGray)
            ,
        )

        Text(
            text = visit.visitDate,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(3.dp) //                                .background(Color.LightGray)
            ,
        )

        Text(
            text = visit.getTotalPelletAmount().toString(),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(3.dp) //                                .background(Color.LightGray)
            ,
        )

        DropdownList(
            itemArray = visit.getPelletToLotNumberArray(),
            selectedIndex = selectedIndex,
            modifier = buttonModifier,
            onItemClick = { selectedIndex = it })
    }
}

}

You have several flaws in your code:

You should not use Array as data structure in Jetpack Compose, as Arrays as a mutable data structure cannot be observed properly by Jetpack Compose.
You should use the LazyColumn itemsIndexed function instead of iterating with forEachIndexed.
To maintain a list and manipulate it, use mutableStateListOf.

Have a look at this simple example, I think it is similar to what you are trying to achieve:
@Composable
MainComposable() {

    val visitList = remember { mutableStateListOf<VisitRowData>() } // creates a MutableList
    val orderedList by remember { mutableStateOf(visitList.toList()) }

    // at some point, add elements to the MutableList
    visitList.addAll(...)
    orderedList = visitList.toList()

    // at some point, sort the list
    orderedList = visitList.sortedWith(...)

    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        itemsIndexed(orderedList) { index, item ->
            Card(...)
        }
    }
}

When you want to set new list data, don't forget to clear the visitList before adding the new elements:
visitList.clear()
visitList.addAll()
sortedList = visitList.toList()


BINGO!!!! Worked perfectly on the first compile/run. Thanks!

I take it back...it was expanding the list...doubling it...each call. Working on that now and will post the final result then close it.

You should call visitList.addAll(...) only once initially. Whenever you want to sort, use orderedList = visitList.sortedWith(...). In case you want to set a new list, you must first clear the visitList by doing visitList.clear().

I tried that, but it only rendered for a brief second then all of the rows disappeared. Working on it.

I got it to render, and now it doesn't add the same set of rows over and over, but the sorting does nothing this way. I updated the code so you and others can see it. It looks like it is following what you suggested to do but there is still something wrong in that clicking the sorting buttons does nothing.

To me it seems like there should be an onValueChange listener assigned to view the orderedList that makes a call to VisitList passing it the orderedList.
